# I am stuck in this error when i retrive name from firestore database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

** Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

[This is the Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqrqV.png)

```js
const createChat = () => {
    const roomName = prompt("Enter Room Name");

    if (roomName) {
      //database stuff
      db.collection('rooms').add({
        name: roomName,
      });
    }
  };

  return !addNewChat ? (
    <div className="sidebarChat">
      <Avatar src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/${seed}.svg`} />
      <div className="sidebarChat__info">
        <h2>Master Chat</h2>
        <h5> {name} </h5>
        <p>Last Message...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
      <div onClick={createChat} className="sidebarChat">
        <h2>Add New Chat</h2>
      </div>

    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see no definition of 'name' as a variable...

Answer (score 1):

The value of name in `<h5> {name} </h5>` seems to be object or html, not string or number to show. React shows this error at that time. Try consoling the value of name.